# Convexity of $h=g+\eta\sqrt{f-g^2}$

Tags: calculus, functions, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose for all $\eta\in[0,1]$ and $\gamma>0$, we define $h:R^{\geq0}\to R^{\geq 0}$ in terms of two convex functions as follows
$$h=g+\eta\sqrt{f-g^2}$$ where $f:R^{\geq0}\to R^{\geq 0}$ and $g:R^{\geq0}\to R^{\geq 0}$. We also know that 
$f,g\geq0$, $f',g'\leq0$, $f'',g''\geq0$, and $f'=-\gamma g$.
How can we show the convexity of $h$?

Comment: Did you take the second derivative of $h$?  That would be the first thing to check.

Comment: No. If I want to take the second derivative of $h$, it would be hard to conclude that $h''$ is positive or negative since the expanded version of $h$ is so complex.

Comment: Can you post the expanded version?  Perhaps we can use $f'=-\gamma g$ to make it simpler than it looks at first.

Comment: I'm getting $h''(t)=-\frac{1}{\gamma}f'''(t)-\frac{\eta}{4}\left[f(t)-\frac{1}{\gamma^2}f'(t)^2\right]^{-3/2}\left[f'(t)-\frac{2}{\gamma^2}f'(t)f''(t)\right]^2+\frac{\eta}{2}\left[f(t)-\frac{1}{\gamma^2}f'(t)^2\right]^{-1/2}\left[f''(t)-\frac{2}{\gamma^2}f'(t)f'''(t)-\frac{2}{\gamma^2}f''(t)^2\right]$

Comment: Can we say that $h''(t)\geq 0$?

Comment: I don't see how. But then I haven't looked very hard, so....

Answer (score 1):

The conjecture is false.  Just take $\eta=\gamma=1$, $f(x)=g(x)=e^{-x}$.  In this case $h(x)$ is concave.

Comment: Thank you. You are totally right. Thank you.